# Update a column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to look for a way to update a column.

Like here:

```
Database: temptestsite
Table: firstsection
then there is username, heading etc (not a log in type situation).
```

Say user sends in the username and I want them to be able to change it. How does one UPDATE this specific column. Anything I have tried so far from w3schools inserts a new column. Could someone please make an example of how to do this with PHP?

Like let there be a text box and then a button or a hyperlink next to it saying "update" or "change", whatever user types in that text box, gets updated in the "usernames" column in the database.

Comment: you start by reading the manual on update https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: it'll also help if you were to post what you tried. so far, this is guesswork. but do read the manual ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general process will be:

1. Check if post data is available

   1. If it is, execute a mysql update call
2. Build the form

Here is some skeleton code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd");

$id = $_GET['id'];

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $link->query("UPDATE users SET username = '".$link->real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' WHERE id = '".$link->real_escape_string($id)."'");
}

$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$link->real_escape_string($id)."'"));

?>

<form method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user['username'] ?>"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Comment: THIS is the first freaking time someone gets what I want on stackoverflow so thanks! On topic: the column I want to update is called username, so would column in  UPDATE table SET column = '".$link ->real_escape_string($_POST['column'])." be username? (also down in name="column" it would be username right? Sorry, this is close to what I want, just want to update the column username with whatever is in the update text box!

Comment: Updated my answer - Does that answer your question?

Comment: And yes people on stack overflow can be very obnoxious. But it is a generally extremely helpful tool if you can put up with them.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work!!!!!!
https://ghostbin.com/paste/v8jgw

thank you maxhud!

Answer (score 0):

There is two update method in rest system,

One of them is PUT , other one is PATCH,

Most frameworks make that request via hidden _method attr, like in laravel

```
<form method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
     <input type="text" name="column"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

PUT is using for changing entire column,
PATCH is just patching as you can understand,

First understand and manage what you really need, then watch & read about them.

As an answer maxhud is explained code version of it.

But it is not the good way to make it with post request.

Comment: I think the OP was asking about database commands rather than HTTP methods.

Comment: I made this explanation when i see the code below the question actually, but when i read again, yes that could be.